# AWS -SES: Adding link in my email template

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, html-email, amazon-ses, aws-sdk-js

I have to send an email using template through AWS SES.

```
{
"Template": {
"TemplateName": "resetPasswordEmailTemplate",
"SubjectPart": "FBO Hangars- Recover Password",
"HtmlPart": "Hi {{name}},\r\n Please click on the below link to recover your password.<b> <a href="">{{link}}</a> <b> The link will be valid for 24 hours. <b> Thank you for using ,Team",
}
}
```

This is my template. issue is the link is not clickable. Also when i inspect the DOM, href attribute is not there in the  tag. Is this something related to configurations? Or the issue with my template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your link should have the following form:

```
<a href="{{link}}">{{link}}</a>
```